# Setting GUID value to Selected Value from Datagrid C#

Tags: c#

I currently have a variable `Guid solutionID`, and I'm trying to have it equal the GUID of the selected row from the datagridview. I'm currently getting an error

> Code CS0029 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Guid'

Here is the code to my "Create" button click where I want to the event to happen. The error is happening on the line

```
Guid SolutionID = dataTable.SelectedRows[5].Index;
```

Complete code:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Guid solutionID = Guid.Empty;
        Guid solutionID = dataTable.SelectedRows[5].Index;

        EntityCollection SolutionComponentsFromSource = SolutionActions.GetSolutionComponents(sourceConnection._orgService, solutionID);

        Entity CreatedSolutionInTarget = SolutionActions.createDuplicateSolution(sourceConnection._orgService, targetConnection._orgService, solutionID);

        SolutionActions.AddSourceComponentsInTarget(sourceConnection._orgService, targetConnection._orgService, solutionID, CreatedSolutionInTarget); 
}
```

And here is the class where I'm using from the entities.

```
internal class CRMSolution
{
    public string friendlyName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public DateTime installedon { get; set; }
    public Guid solutionID { get; set; } 
}
```

I already know that it's for sure in the fifth column because [0] is a count column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid solutionID = ((CRMSolution)dataTable.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).solutionid;
```

I was messing up with the SelectedRows index